# Should a function be put in a separate file if it requires importing larger libraries?

Tags: performance, python-import

I am segmenting my python program, creating separate python files for each function. These functions will then be imported when required.

Some functions require importing libraries. I was wondering if repeated calls to these functions in a single file will slow down the speed of the code. i.e. The libraries have to be imported again every call.

The libraries the function requires include bs4, requests, and re.

This is the code I am using for the function.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# Add User-Agent parameter
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}

# Retrieve all links from a given webpage
# Separate links into internal and external links
def get_links(url, siteurl):

    # Retrieve content from url
    page_link = url
    page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser",
                                 from_encoding="iso-8859-1")

    # Create sets for internal and external links
    internal = set([])
    external = set([])

    # Retrieve links and sorts them into internal and external links
    for unsorted_link in page_content.findAll(
        'a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http")}):
        link = unsorted_link.get('href')
        if link.startswith(siteurl):
            internal.add(link)
        else:
            external.add(link)

    return internal, external
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out some information looking at the console and fiddling around with code. I use the Spyder IDE.

"User Module Reloader (UMR): UMR forces Python to reload modules which were imported when executing a file in a Python or IPython console with the runfile function."

From,
http://www.psych.mcgill.ca/labs/mogillab/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/doc/ipythonconsole.html

*During this first import, the byte code is generated (.pyc file) if necessary and the imported module code object is cached in sys.modules. Then, when re-importing the same module, this cached code object will be directly used even if the source code file (.py[w] file) has changed meanwhile.*

and

*The User Module Reloader (UMR) is a Spyder console’s exclusive feature that forces the Python interpreter to reload modules completely when executing a Python script.*

Hence I am assuming that the modules only reload once on execution and not while the Python script is running.

Furthermore I tested the total runtime a few times each and both ways took around 1.8secs per execution on average. So it seems there is no significant performance difference.